# How to create a 'CallBack' action after getting a Code from Authentication Server in OAuth2 in Web Application Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm Providing an 'OAuthHandler' for non-famouse and overriding some OAuthHandler methods to communicate between User Agent (Client) and Remote Authenticate Server.

Below is my controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class MyCompanyLoginController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] string provider)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(provider))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if (!await HttpContext.IsProviderSupportedAsync(provider))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet("~/signout")]
    [HttpPost("~/signout")]
    public IActionResult SignOutCurrentUser()
    {
        return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

And I added some classes to handle my requests: [here is the importance of those that overrode from the `OAuthHandler` class]

```
public partial class MyCompanyAuthenticationHandler : OAuthHandler<MyCompanyAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public MyCompanyAuthenticationHandler(
        [NotNull] IOptionsMonitor<MyCompanyAuthenticationOptions> options,
        [NotNull] ILoggerFactory logger,
        [NotNull] UrlEncoder encoder,
        [NotNull] ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {}

    // STEP 1: CREATE CHALLENGE URL
    protected override string BuildChallengeUrl([NotNull] AuthenticationProperties properties, [NotNull] string redirectUri)
    {
        var scopeParameter = properties.GetParameter<ICollection<string>>(OAuthChallengeProperties.ScopeKey);
        var scope = scopeParameter != null ? FormatScope(scopeParameter) : FormatScope();

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string?>
        {
            ["client_id"] = Options.ClientId,
            ["response_type"] = "code",
            ["scope"] = scope
        };

        if (Options.UsePkce)
        {
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(256 / 8);
            var codeVerifier = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(bytes);

            // Store this for use during the code redemption.
            properties.Items.Add(OAuthConstants.CodeVerifierKey, codeVerifier);

            var challengeBytes = SHA256.HashData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
            var codeChallenge = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(challengeBytes);

            parameters[OAuthConstants.CodeChallengeKey] = codeChallenge;
            parameters[OAuthConstants.CodeChallengeMethodKey] = OAuthConstants.CodeChallengeMethodS256;
        }

        var state = Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(properties);            

        parameters["redirect_uri"] = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(redirectUri, "state", state);

        return QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(Options.AuthorizationEndpoint, parameters);
    }

    // STEP 2 : CHANGE CODE WITH ACCESS_TOKEN
    protected override async Task<OAuthTokenResponse> ExchangeCodeAsync([NotNull] OAuthCodeExchangeContext context)
    {
        var tokenRequestParameters = new Dictionary<string, string?>()
        {
            ["client_id"] = Options.ClientId,
            ["client_secret"] = Options.ClientSecret,
            ["redirect_uri"] = context.RedirectUri,
            ["code"] = context.Code,
            ["grant_type"] = "authorization_code"
        };

        // Add CodeVerify to tokenRequestParameters
        if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue(OAuthConstants.CodeVerifierKey, out var codeVerifier))
        {
            tokenRequestParameters.Add(OAuthConstants.CodeVerifierKey, codeVerifier);
            context.Properties.Items.Remove(OAuthConstants.CodeVerifierKey);
        }

        var endpoint = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(Options.TokenEndpoint, tokenRequestParameters);

        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Options.TokenEndpoint);
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tokenRequestParameters);

        using var response = await Backchannel.SendAsync(request, Context.RequestAborted);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // An error occurred while retrieving an OAuth token.
        }

        var payload = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(Context.RequestAborted));            

        return OAuthTokenResponse.Success(payload);
    }

    // STEP 3: access to UserInformation with Access Token
    protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateTicketAsync(
        [NotNull] ClaimsIdentity identity,
        [NotNull] AuthenticationProperties properties,
        [NotNull] OAuthTokenResponse tokens)
    {
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokens.AccessToken);

        using var response = await Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, Context.RequestAborted);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // An error occurred while retrieving the user profile.
        }

        using var payload = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(Context.RequestAborted));

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var context = new OAuthCreatingTicketContext(principal, properties, Context, Scheme, Options, Backchannel, tokens, payload.RootElement.GetProperty("data"));
        context.RunClaimActions();

        await Events.CreatingTicket(context);
        return new AuthenticationTicket(context.Principal!, context.Properties, Scheme.Name);
    }        
}
```

As you know, after running `https:\\Development-Domain.com\signin` by post method (second action), a Challenge is started and will redirect to `BuildChallengeUrl()` and return a Url with `Code` and `State`. The next action would be `ExchangeCodeAsync()` to change the `Code` sent by the remote server with an `AccessToken`.

The question is, which action or method was missed in this process? Will my `ExchangeCodeAsync()` call automatically after the `BuildChallengeUrl()` handler, or do I need to put some action to continue to authorize the user?

**Update #1**: I added a callback action to get info from 'QueryString' in controller to call next method of handler class:

```
[HttpPost("~/signin-oidc")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Callback([FromForm] string provider)
    {
        var code = Request.Query["code"];
        var state = Request.Query["state"];

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if (!await HttpContext.IsProviderSupportedAsync(provider))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return {?};

    }
```

What code must I write in {?} to request for Access Token from TokenEndpoint?

Comment: You need to send a second request when you get the correct response.  The second response will look different and have a different IActionResult.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. Do you mean I need to put action with the same callback route and call the second method? Right?

Comment: No.  The response message is different.  So you need a route for each type message.  The IActionResult does a deserialize of the response and will take a different action depending on the response.  You have to specify the action with a route.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Comment: @jdweng, at this time I need to call ExchangeCodeAsync() from the handler class. What should I do in this regard?

Comment: Nothing special.  Just call it like you would normally.

Answer (score 1):

Except callback action other code are in-line with Authorisation code flow.

In PKCE Authorization code flow, you should match with flow mentioned here, that will help pass security validation / testing post production.

[How it works, Authorization Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce#how-it-works)

Answer to question,

CallBack action an endpoint action method of `callback url` should trigger and make post request to token endpoint of authorisation server with `code` received as query string in `CallBack Url` with `Code Verifier` created with `Code Challenge` and on successful post it will return access-token, refresh-token, id-token, .... based on your configuration. You will need to specify callback url also with `client_id` and `client_secret` in configuration.

re-arranging code based on this [How it works, Authorization Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce#how-it-works)  will help.

Comment: in login action I have the Challenge() method to call BuildChallengeUrl() from the handler class, but after callback which method will help the user to proceed to the next step(get a token) from TokenEndpoint. this is where I am confused and I don't know what should I do exactly.

Comment: From your OIDC provider you should get token url and other configuration details from `.well-known-configuration` url.  Use token endpoint and make a POST call to that endpoint with 2 parameters -1. authorisation code ( will receive  in callback url ). -2. code verifier, 
Once your receive token you should set it as cookie in user's browser preferably (httpOnly) from callback itself. once cookie ( token ) saved in user's browser it will come to server in every request from client side (users browser) then in `Authorization` filter can read that cookie and validate token to access token.

Answer (score 0):

After figuring out and researching Microsoft .Net Core OAuth libraries, I got the answer and I would like to share it with you:

As you know, we no need to write any code in callback action for running the next method in the `MyCompanyAuthenticationHandler` class because all the process is automatic and event-based and all of them are provided in the Microsoft OAuthHandler class. You need to write some code inside the `Callback` action just for registering `User` after the authentication process.

Even you can use Microsoft ExternalLogin Identity pages for the registration of an external User.

Also, I decided to create a project on `GitHub` and I'd like to share it here
[OktaProvider](https://github.com/ayubamini/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Okta), maybe everyone needs to add external authentication for non-famous companies.